# Optimal solution to fit the items in multiple capacity bags

Tags: algorithm, optimization, dynamic-programming, distributed-computing

I have been working on this problem (https://github.com/alexpchung/File-Distribution-Planning/blob/master/README.pdf) where I need to find an optimal solution to place the files in the node.

Here is my algorithm which I have used so far

- Say number of nodes is N.
- keep track of available file size for every node iterate through
  every file, it has N choices to go to (assuming file fits in etc)
- Recursively evaluate for every

Another solution which I have thought is to iterate through each and every node and do a knapsack 0/1. Unfortunately, i got struck because since the node sizes are not fixed it will be an incorrect solution.

If you have any pointers that would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can benchmark this:

- Sort two lists.(capacity,size, all increasing)
- Start from biggest file.
- Also start from biggest node.
- Check if it fits

  - true: put it in
  - false: put it to "failed" list since no bigger node exists.
- If selected(biggest) node is full, iterate next smaller node
- İterate to next smaller file.
- go back to checking step until either one of conditions true

  - all files assigned, empty nodes exist
  - all nodes full, unplaced files exist
- (*)sort only nodes on their empty spaces(empty nodes exist=true or both true)

  - duplicate node list with opposite order

    - check if "latest added file" on least "empty space"d can fit biggest "empty space"d node and if transition yields equal/balanced empty space on both

      - true: send file to that node
      - false: iterate on next "least empty space" node since that file can't fit others neighter
    - iterate both lists(and remove refined pairs from lists)
- if at least 1 files could be refined, go to (*)

Comment: Can you please explain this step.

_ (*)sort only nodes on their empty spaces(empty nodes exist=true or both true)
_ duplicate node list with opposite order
 -check if "latest added file" on least "empty space"d can fit biggest "empty space"d node and if transition yields equal/balanced empty space on both
true: send file to that node
false: iterate on next "least empty space" node since that file can't fit others neighter
_ iterate both lists(and remove refined pairs from lists)
_ if at least 1 files could be refined, go to (*)

Comment: binding first node with the last one, then probably n-1th with 2nd and then probably n-2nd with 3rd.... so mostly full ones will share with mostly empty ones